# Cannot execute approxPolyDP()

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, contour

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image=cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Desert.jpg",1);
    Mat imagegray, output, imageresult;;

    int thresh=150;

    cvtColor(image, imagegray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<vector<Point>>contours;
    vector<Vec4i>hierarchy;

    Canny(imagegray, imageresult,thresh, thresh*2);

    findContours(imageresult,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));

    Mat drawing=Mat::zeros(imagegray.size(),CV_8UC3);
    approxPolyDP(contours,imageresult,100,true);

    namedWindow("Display",1);
    imshow("Display",imageresult);
    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

In the code given above the

> approxPolyDP()

function is not working. On running it with breakpoints the program does not execute after this function. What is wrong with the code given here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following codes works

```
Mat image=cvLoadImage("face1.jpg",1);
Mat imagegray, output, imageresult;;
Mat canny;

cvtColor(image, imagegray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

vector<vector<Point>>contours;
vector<Vec4i>hierarchy;

Canny(imagegray,canny,50,150);

findContours(canny,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));



   Mat drawing=Mat::zeros(imagegray.size(),CV_8UC3);
 vector<Point>contours_approx;
    approxPolyDP(contours[0],contours_approx,100,true)
//approxPolyDP(contours,imageresult,100,true);

drawContours(image,contours,-1,Scalar(255,0,0));

namedWindow("Display");
imshow("Display",image);
waitKey(0);
return(0);
```

findcontour() needs a canny/threshold binary image for the input.

approxPolyDP() is to approximates a curve to another curve(vector of points).

Comment: Thanks. Also, can I count the number of sides in the image using approxPolyDP()? If so, how?

Comment: Also please check the question and see if you can figure out the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130735/matchshapes-function-not-working